# Why can't I pass a local class variable to newly instantiated class in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have a class as bellow, that contain `baseUrl` and `apollo`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  private let baseUrl = "http://myserver.org:4000"
  private let apollo = ApolloClient(url: URL(string: "http://myserver.org:4000")!)

}
```

Notice that `http://myserver.org:4000` is shared across both, so I like to share them

I tried both

```
private let apollo = ApolloClient(url: URL(string: baseUrl)!)
// This error out stating 
// `Cannot use instance member 'baseUrl' within property initializer; 
// property initializers run before 'self' is available`
```

and

```
private let apollo = ApolloClient(url: URL(string: self.baseUrl)!)
// This error out stating 
// `Value of type '(ViewController) -> () -> ViewController' has no member 'baseUrl'`
```

How could I have them share? I thought it's something simple in a language to pass on a constant variable to another class using it. (Sorry, I'm not very familiar with Swift, if this is somethign simple., as I'm more Android dev).

Answer (score 1):

You can make `baseUrl` static:

```
private static let baseUrl = "http://myserver.org:4000"
private let apollo = ApolloClient(url: URL(string: ViewController.baseUrl)!)
```

The error message says that instance members can't be used before `self` is fully initialised, which is fair enough if you think about it, so we make it static.

Alternatively, do it in the initialisers:

```
private let baseUrl : String = "http://myserver.org:4000"
private let apollo: ApolloClient

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    apollo = ApolloClient(url: URL(string: baseUrl)!)
    super.init(coder: coder)
}

override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
    apollo = ApolloClient(url: URL(string: baseUrl)!)
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}
```

> Why can't you use `baseUrl` directly?

This is explained briefly [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID232):

> If you use a closure to initialize a property, remember that the rest of the instance has not yet been initialized at the point that the closure is executed. This means that you cannot access any other property values from within your closure, even if those properties have default values. You also cannot use the implicit self property, or call any of the instance’s methods.

Although you are not really using closures here, the idea is the same. The reason still applies. Note that this is different from Java, where fields are initialised in textual order, making something like this possible:

```
private int a = 1;
private int b = a + 1;
private int c = b + 2;
```

But in Swift, the order in which the properties are initialised is not specified.

Comment: Making static properties just to get around this isn't best practice.  Using initialisers is a far better option as it's what they're there for.  If desperate to avoid them, using a lazy var would be a better option than a static constant IMO (the flip side is it's then mutable, but it's unlikely in this scenario that would be a big risk).

Comment: @flanker Well, I am the kind of person who really hates making a property that could be immutable mutable. I guess it depends on taste and style.

Comment: I'm with you there.  I don't like the lazy var compromise much more than the static constant - both are workarounds.  Using the `init` is the 'proper' way IMO.

Answer (score 1):

According to the initialization rules it's not allowed to initialize constant properties which depend on each other.

Alternatively initialize `apollo` lazily, that means the instance is created when being accessed the first time

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private let baseUrl = URL(string:"http://myserver.org:4000")!
    private lazy var apollo = ApolloClient(url: baseUrl)    
}
```

Only `var`iables can be initialized lazily but as the variable is private it's not relevant.