# Custom Decoder error due to self before all stored properties are initialized

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, decodable

I have the following `Decodable` model:

```
struct VideoResponse: Decodable {
    let videos: [Video]
    let lastVideos: [Video]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case videos
    } 

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    
        let videos = try container.decode([Video].self, forKey: .videos)
        self.videos = sort(videos)
        self.lastVideos = computeLastVideos(from: self.videos)
    }
}
```

The above does not compile since I'm trying to use both `sort` and `compute(from:)` before before all stored properties are initialized.

> 'self' used before all stored properties are initialized.

To fix the problem I could indeed move the logic within the the two method inside `init(from:)` decoder. I would avoid it since the `VideoResponse` could be used as a plain `struct`.

```
extension VideoReponse {
    init(videos: [Videos]) { 
        // same setup here...
    }
}
```

Any idea on how to fix this in order to avoid duplicated code?

Comment: Does `sort` and `computeLastVideos` actually use `self` in their implementations though?

Comment: You can declare `sort` and `computeLastVideos` to be static to fix this.

Comment: Code of `sort` & `computeLastVideos(from:)`? But, couldn't they be static method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call methods on `self` before stored properties are all initialised because the methods could potentially access an uninitialised property (See also [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59016177/5133585)), and who knows what happens then? You can tell Swift that `sort` and `computeLastVideos` *won't* access `self` at all, by putting the word `static`:

```
static func sort(_ videos: [Video]) -> [Video] { ... }
static func computeLastVideos(from videos: [Video]) -> [Video] { ... }
```

You would also have to put the sorted videos into a temporary variable `sortedVideos` first, because you can't access `self.videos`:

```
let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
let videos = try container.decode([Video].self, forKey: .videos)
let sortedVideos = VideoResponse.sort(videos)
self.lastVideos = VideoResponse.computeLastVideos(from: sortedVideos)
self.videos = sortedVideos
```

If `sort` and `computerLastVideos` *does* access `self` though, you are out of luck, and have to make `videos` a non-`let`, and initialise it first, then change it later. You can't guarantee to Swift that `sort` and `computeLastVideos` will *only access the initialised part* of `self`.

Comment: I was trying to avoid static methods but I think it's the only way to go.

Comment: @LorenzoB Why don't you like static methods?

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion:

1. Declare `lastVideos` as lazy
2. Sort with a built-in API

---

```
struct VideoResponse: Decodable {
    let videos: [Video]
    lazy var lastVideos : [Video] = {
       return self.computeLastVideos(from: self.videos)
    }()

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case videos } 

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)        
        self.videos = try container.decode([Video].self, forKey: .videos).sorted(by: { ... })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The only problem with `lazy` is that if you assign again `VideoResponse`, accessing `lastVideos` means the computation will be performed again. What if the computation takes too long and I'm in the main thread?

Comment: No, the computation is performed once and not until the property is accessed the first time. That’s a significant benefit of lazy instantiated properties.